# Get image stored in online database as type 'image' as a byte array

Tags: php, android, sql, sql-server

I am creating an Android app where I need to retrieve images stored in an online MS SQL Database. The table is called ImagesData and it contains a column called Image_Data which is of the type 'image'. The content of that column is in hexadecimal values (It starts with 0x9F4AB7DA7.... and so on). Each entry is approximately 43679 characters long (filled with hexadecimal characters as mentioned above). My doubt is how do I retrieve this hexadecimal data and display it as an ImageView in my app.

Note: I tried retrieving the data using a PHP script, but it gives an error saying "Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. (severity 16)"

```
<?php

include('config.php');

  $query= "select * from ImagesData where Image_id = '7'";
  $result = mssql_query($query);


  while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo $row["Image_Data"];
 }

 mssql_close();
 ?>
```

I tried a modified code suggested here([MSSQL Query issue in PHP and querying text data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414890/mssql-query-issue-in-php-and-querying-text-data)) but that too gave an error saying "Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Explicit conversion from data type image to text is not allowed. (severity 16)".

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$query= "select CAST(Image_data AS TEXT) AS Image_Data from ImagesData where Image_id = '7'";
$result = mssql_query($query);


while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row["Image_Data"];
}

mssql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing images, we usually store the location and name of the image in the db... If the image is stored in for eg C:/xampp/htdocs/website/images/image.jpg, in the database, we save the name of the image. If the location can be found through a relative path, eg: website.com/images/, we set the path of the image in php to be images/$row[name of image from db]. Since the links are relative, your image will automatically load from website.com/images/image.jpg or localhost/website/images/image.jpg.

Hope you understood how to save images and retrieve them. We don't save image data in the db, we save the location where the image is going to be saved in the db.

Comment: You are not getting the point. We (as in my website developers) do not store the images in our local server at all. Once a user uploads a photo (through the website which is coded in aspx), the c# code converts the image into a byte array and stores that byte array in the database. When the user wishes to view the photo, the byte array is fetched from the database, an image is generated from that byte array and then displayed to the user. My question is how do I fetch this byte array from an android app? Hope you get what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
   $image = base64_decode($thumb);

        /** check if the image is db */
        if($image!=null)
        {

            $db_img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
            Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            imagejpeg($db_img);

        }
exit;
```

Comment: what is $thumb exactly?

Comment: $thumb is the binary data from the db table