# SQL Server: "Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data..." issue, but can't change FreeTDS version

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode

I'm having a familiar issue when trying to `SELECT` columns of type `nvarchar` from my SQL Server Database using PHP:

```
Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.
```

I know that I can workaround this using `SELECT CAST(columnName as TEXT) as columnName from tableName`... but that's hacky and annoying. Plus [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) won't work as long as there's this error, and I can't configure Adminer to `CAST` its column names.

In [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414970/1603071) and in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) many people have mentioned that you can fix this problem by changing the file `/etc/freetds.conf/`... but I'm on Windows, not *nix, so no such file exists. (I contacted support at my hosting company to confirm this.)

Is there any way I can select `nvarchar` columns without having to add the annoying and tedious `CAST` boilerplate every time? And to get Adminer to work?

Or is my only option to switch to a different driver than DB-Library?

Comment: Did you sort this out? I am also having same issue

Comment: Sorry, this project ended up being abandoned... can't remember for the life of me if I solved this particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

Windows solution:-
You can always use Windows drivers for connecting to Mssql datasbase.(The Native drivers for windows are available and are not hard to install I belive. I can send that if it is that required.)

I have the solution for making connection to mssql when your machine is Linux based (I would specifically say Centos).
The mistakes I was making was I didn't configure the FreeTds that was located in /etc/freetds.conf
it will not be here in case of Ubuntu systems.

Check the line that says "**A typical windows system**" configure that part
Please check this below one

```
[connectionname]
host = **nameOrIpofTheServer**
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = utf-8
```

Use the connection name in your code.
**Note if you want these settings to work use connection name**
The connection object the PDO will look something like this:-

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=**$hostname**:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw"); //
```

General one

```
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host='**connectionname**':$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

//actual connnection with connection name
Now try to select data from your mssql database having UTF-8 characters.
I will work.

Next issue that you will face while working on this environment will be:-
**Saving the UTF-8 Characters to database**.
A simple but complex solution you will have to prefix N in front of database Query where you will be assigning value to the field.
For Example:- UPDATE [users] SET [Address]=N'большой' WHERE [ID]= 1;
Here Address is UTF-8 Field. Like NTEXT, NCHAR and NVARCHAR.