# Microsoft SQL Server error with Laravel: Why this solves my mistake?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, freetds, nvarchar

I am creating an application in `Laravel`, which accesses information stored in a remote database `Microsoft SQL Server`.

And I have encountered an error, which I solved; but I do not quite know why...

## The Problem

I created a "*users*" table within the database in the `Microsoft SQL Server`, in order to use the application through a login system: ***Works well.***

My job is to display information from the tables found in the existing database in `Microsoft SQL Server` ... so I have created the `model` of one of this tables —called, for example, `Sales`— **BUT** when I try to query information with:

```
$sale = Sales::find("1");
```

I get the next error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4004 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [4004] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

The same error with other `Eloquent` ways and `Fluent`.

## The problematic table

These are some of the columns which has the queried table:

[image: nvarchar]

## How I solved this:

I have solved making two changes in two configuration files:

---

#### 1) Inside **/etc/freetds/freetds.conf**

I changed the tds version from:

```
tds version = 4.2
```

to

```
tds version = 8.0
```

And set client charset as follow:

```
client charset = UTF-8
```

---

#### 2) Inside **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

```
mssql.charset = "UTF-8"

default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

## My question: Why this works?

From what I've read this is due to:

> *Laravel uses db-library (if it's available) to connect to Sql Server which cannot receive unicode data from MSSQL. (1,2)* — From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23919993/4359029)

So I guess it may be due to the type fields `nvarchar`... But when I changed my model to remove all field with `nvarchar`, I still get the same problem...

## Fragment of my Laravel database config: *config/database.php*

```
 [...]

'default' => 'sqlsrv',

    [...]
    'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => 'foo.bar',
        'database' => 'MyDataBase',
        'username' => 'UserName',
        'password' => 'MySecret',
        'prefix' => ''
    )

[...]
```

I do not know if there is another [configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database) for `sqlsrv` to specify the version of `FreeTDS`.

## Result of `tsql -C` command:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tds version = 4.2` is the global default for FreeTDS, but very out of date, doesn't support `UTF-8`, and has been problematic even when connecting to modern version of SQL Server. Please see the documentation here:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Your `nvarchar` columns will require `UTF-8` throughout your stack.

Please also note that `tds version = 8.0` is deprecated, and not valid, likely to be removed in a future version of FreeTDS. You *probably* want `tds version = 7.2`, or `tds version = 7.3`, depending on what version of the FreeTDS driver you have installed. You can find the FreeTDS version installed by using `tsql -C` from the command line.

UPDATE: the key was changing the `tds version = 7.2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  When I change `tds version = 8.0` to `7.2` or `7.3` I get the same error which I exposed in my question.

Likewise, when I use `tsql -C` I only see the `4.2` version. Do you know how to install other version? (*7.2, as you recommend*)

Comment: Make sure you have the TDS version set to 7.2 in you freetds.conf (both in the global section and DSN). But I'm guessing you really need it as an option in your Laravel connection string. Can you include your Laravel code where you specify database connection info?

Comment: I had the TDS version (*7.2*) inside my `freetds.conf`, but I get the same error which I exposed in my question...  I will update my question with my Laravel database configuration.

Comment: I'm not a Laravel user, but if it is like Python or Perl, try adding `'TDS_Version' => '7.2',` to your connection string.

Comment: I will try now. Thanks! I'll tell you in a while.

Comment: When you ran `tsql -C`, where did it say your freetds.conf way? I'm curious why it is reporting `4.2` if you changed to `7.2` in the `[global]` section of the freetds.conf config.

Comment: Wow, I changed again my `freetds.conf` to `7.2` version and all works well... Maybe just I tried the `7.3` , since `7.3` does not work for me... Probably I mistook me, hehe. Regarding to `tsql -C`, now, having the `7.2` release set, I keep getting the same message. I will update my answer with an image.

Comment: TDS versions are tricky, but I'm glad we got it figured out! I've got a pull request into FreeTDS which will hopefully explain this a bit more clearly in the documentation: https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/pull/71/files

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well FreeTDS 4.2 is way too old. It has many limitations. You should consider a higher version.

But anyway. FreeTDS in compbination with PHP isn't a good choice. Especially with the latest PHP versions.

You should change to ODBC11 or ODBC13, which is available for Linux too.

But again: Your basic fault is the low FreeTDS version. It depends on the version of SQL Server you trying to use. You can see a compatibility table [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I tried to install `ODBC13` (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50419) in my Debian but I guess it's incompatible with this operating system... By the way, could you tell me why FreeTDS isn't a good choice in compbination with PHP? also... How to specify if I want to use `FreeTDS` or `ODBC13`?

Comment: There are quite a few known issues with the Microsoft provided ODBC drivers for Linux. FreeTDS is more reliable on Linux. If you're interested in some of the details: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/FbBcUCzrSZo/9uCGTa0ZAQAJ

Comment: Yes it "might" be reliable. We use it too, in combination with php. But it works only with many workarounds. If you try to use symphony and thinks like that, it will be a pain. But as a I said, it might be reliable. It depends on your application size and pressure.