# MSSQL & SQL data type alternatives?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, sqlsrv, mssql-jdbc

I have to work on a project connecting to a SQL Server DB, while working with PHP and a Laravel framework.

My issue is with the data types and where I would be able to change them into fully functional and more 'conventional' SQL data types. So let's take NVARCHAR for example, would I be able to change into a normal VARCHAR?

The types I have are:

- `NCHAR`
- `NVARCHAR`
- `GEOGRAPHY`

I've read over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897004/laravel-generated-sql-throws-error-only-on-specific-tables) that :

> Laravel uses db-library (if it's available) to connect to Sql Server
>   which cannot receive unicode data from MSSQL. (1,2)

Is there anyone in the crowd that work with Laravel and preformed such a task?

Comment: NCHAR and NVARCHAR are completely "conventional". They allow for the extended character set. This page should prove extremely helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: As is GEOGRAPHY...  What is the actual issue you are facing here?

Comment: I should've elaborated on "conventional"... Laravel (and i'm sure other frameworks) have specific models and schemes that use conventional datatypes, if you're familiar with Laravel eloquent models, in anycase I will amend my question to clear things up.

Comment: @iamdave I am looking for an 'eloquent' way of building my DB co-joined with laravel, I can't find anywhere any relative information for using the datatypes I have with Laravel, wondering if anyone came across this and have an option of dealing with this. Thanks.

Comment: @DudeOfLayers  Thank you for the additional clarification.  Providing a full context and explanation of the issues you are facing is essential in receiving targeted and relevant advice.

Comment: `dblibrary` is ancient and the fact that many Unix-based tools still require or promote its use should be considered criminal, seeing as how it selects bad and unintuitive defaults for execution options like `ANSI_NULLS`. Consider using an ODBC connection and the [native ODBC client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh568451) instead, if supported by your setup. Mapping `NVARCHAR` to whatever string type your framework uses simply should not be an issue and should certainly not require you to change the database!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following convention I found from [MSSQL data types to MYSQL data types](http://skplunkerin.com/mssql-data-types-to-mysql-data-types/)

```
NCHAR => CHAR/LONGTEXT
NVARCHAR => VARCHAR/MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT
```

Still couldn't find a solution for `GEOGRAPHY` type. I'll keep you posted.

Found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx) on `GEOGRAPHY` but it clearly doesn't mention a counterpart to it.

Comment: So you're saying that I can use varchar freely to replace nvarchar?
I reckon the DBA did this since we will have every language in the world here. Will look fwd to your answer re geography too.

Comment: @DudeOfLayers  I am not sure about MySQL, but in MSSQL definitely not.  Converting from `nvarchar` to `varchar` will not retain international character sets.

Comment: I agree + all the workarounds I found around the web are just too staggered and would not be accepted in any code review, thanks all and will be waiting for any future answers.