# MS SQL Server Query issue in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem, obviosly with php script.
I am trying to get some data from mssql but I am getting an error:

> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Unicode data
>   in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients
>   using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.
>   (severity 16) in /var/www/mssql_test_saop.php on line 63
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
>   /var/www/mssql_test_saop.php on line 63 Rezultati za:
>
> SELECT * FROM VseClaniceISPAPDokument

This is structure of table VseClaniceISPAPDokument

```
    ([NazivPU] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [MesObr] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [LetoObr] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [IspapXML] [xml] NULL)
```

This is php script:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
    <meta charset="windows-1250">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
        table * {
            font-family: "Arial Narrow";
            font-size: 10px;
        }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <pre><?

      // Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or
      // <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
      $server = '10.10.10.110:51541';

      // Connect to MSSQL
      $link = mssql_connect($server, 'tinem', '****');

      $db = "saopsf"; //skupna
      //$db = "saopopn013";

      if (!$link || !mssql_select_db($db, $link)) {
     die('Unable to connect or select database!' .                       mssql_get_last_message());
      }

     // Do a simple query, select the version of
      // MSSQL and print it.
     $version = mssql_query('SELECT @@VERSION');
     $row = mssql_fetch_array($version);

      print_r($row);

     // Clean up
     mssql_free_result($version);

     ?>
      </pre>
     <?


       function run_sql($sql) {
       $query = mssql_query($sql);

       echo "Rezultati za: <pre>$sql</pre>";

       echo mssql_num_rows($query). " vrstic<br>";

       if (mssql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        //$data = mssql_fetch_assoc($data);
       ?>
      <table border="1" style="font-size: 10;font-family: arial;">
        <tr>
            <?
            for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_fields($query); ++$i) {
                $field = mssql_fetch_field($query, $i);
                echo "<th>".$field->name."</th>";
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?
            while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($row as $field) {
                    echo "<td>" . $field . "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
      <?
     }

    mssql_free_result($query);
     }




       run_sql("SELECT * FROM VseClaniceISPAPDokument");

        ?>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: May be some help here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414890/mssql-query-issue-in-php-and-querying-text-data)

Comment: thanks danjam,  tds version and client charset solved that!

Comment: Nale: What version? What client charset?